# JavaScript/jQuery check that array contains all a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JavaScript or jQuery, I want to check through an array to make sure all items have a certain value. So for example, if I am checking for "active" in the following arrays, I want:

```
["active"] => true
["active", "active", "active"] => true
["active", "pending", "active", "active"] => false
["pending"] => false
```

What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Loop through the array and compare each value to the first (zeroth) value. If they're different, the test is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the JS Array function called `every`:

`array.every(function(x) { return x == "active"; });`

This will return `true` only if every element in `array` equals `active`.

Comment: Just make sure this is [Compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with what you are developing for.

Comment: array.every is implemented in most modern browsers and IE9+.
Underscorejs is useful if you need to support IE7+. If you want to avoid all libraries go with @Blazemonger 's suggestion.